# Vue.js with vue material; scrolling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

I'm currently working on a project, where I use [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) with [vue material](http://vuematerial.io), and [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) (latest releases of each one). I don't know why, but if the main-content is higher then the screen height, I can not scroll down, there is no scroll in the browser, just the element is out of the screen.

E.g.: If I made a dynamical list, if I put 3 `component` to the list they are visible, but I put 10 `component` then I can see 4-5, there is no way to scroll down. Now I figured out if I define the `max-height` in css of the `md-layout` of the list `component` (what contains the list elements `component`) then, a scroll is appear, but on the `md-layout` element, and not on the page.

```
  <main class="main-content">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </main>
```

**Why does the vue.js and/or vue material work like this?**

Thanks for the responses in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally copied the Vue material example and it has overflow hidden in the CSS.   You need to change this if you have done this.

Comment: Would you be willing to take a look at another Vue Material question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952741/how-to-set-up-flexible-grid-in-vue-material